# How to add a draggable "textfield" to add text over images in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, photo

I am creating a Meme generator application in flutter..i just need to know is there a way that user itself can add text over image and drag that text anywhere in the image area...so that the picture would look funny .I tried dragbox widget but dont know how can i use that for textfield..so that i too can move my text anywhere on the image.[I need something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgeH5.jpg)

Comment: You can include images in your post. You should at least an example of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
    class TextOverImage extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text('Text Over Image Image Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: Container(
            height: 300,
            width: 300,
            child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            image: new NetworkImage(
                                "https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/funny-face-baby-27701492.jpg"),
                            fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                ),
                HomePage()
                ],
            ),
            ),
        ),
        );
    }
    }

    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
    }

    class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
    Offset offset = Offset.zero;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
        child: Positioned(
            left: offset.dx,
            top: offset.dy,
            child: GestureDetector(
                onPanUpdate: (details) {
                setState(() {
                    offset = Offset(
                        offset.dx + details.delta.dx, offset.dy + details.delta.dy);
                });
                },
                child: SizedBox(
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
                child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Center(
                    child: Text("You Think You Are Funny But You Are Not",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 28.0,
                            color: Colors.red)),
                    ),
                ),
                )),
        ),
        );
    }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the solution @amitprajapati..its working totally fine..but a small additional part is yet missing..is there a way i can manually drag and drop the text at another position on the image itself..i have some idea about **"Dragbox"** widget..but dont know how can i integrate text within it..if you would suggest some ,it would be great..!

Comment: yes @amit prajapati..i tried the updated code but i am facing the error of "Media query size"..so since yesterday ..i am trying to solve the issue..but dint got through

Comment: I tried now..it worked like a charm..Thank you so much for the solution@amit prajapati..!

Comment: Enjoy your code, don't forgot to check answer as mark

Comment: Thank you so much again..i checked the answer as marked..Your efforts are priceless..!

Comment: @amitprajapati..is there a way i can add the same draggable text on a image captured from camera/gallery..?..if there is please try to answer this,it would be very helpful for me..i searched on google but dint found any..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58022688/how-to-add-a-text-on-a-image-captured-from-camera-or-gallery-in-flutter?noredirect=1#comment102449098_58022688

Comment: @amitprajapati.What if i want to save the image with the text in firebase storage..any help would be appreciated..thanks

Comment: @akshaydhone will look into this and update you to night

Comment: how can we add more text?

Comment: @muhammad I'm not getting actually what your question is. If you want text there is just add text in Text widget

Comment: @AmitPrajapati i waana to get this can user add their text by clicking on Floating Button...Like *PixelLab* Add Text In Image

Comment: @muhammad it's not Dynamic you have to do your self sorry 