# How to add a text on a "image" captured from "camera" or "Gallery" in flutter?

Tags: text, flutter, dart, camera, gallery

I am implementing a Meme creator app in flutter.what i need is when a user captures image from camera or gallery,i want to add a text on that captured/Selected image..i have implemented the feature of cropping the image but dint found to add text on it.I googled for the same and dint find the exact solution for it..Any help is appreciated

Comment: you have to use [Canvas](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas-class.html) API

Comment: Thanks @pskink.It would be appreciated if you post answer as an example for me..Thanks for the effort

Comment: a hint: you need to call `Canvas.drawParagraph()` method - the docs say: *"Draws the text in the given Paragraph into this canvas at the given Offset.

The Paragraph object must have had Paragraph.layout called on it first."*

Comment: i got your point @pskink..but i am new to flutter technology..if you post a small example as an answer,it would be very helpful for me.thanks

Comment: did you google for: `flutter canvas tutorial`? there is a lot of examples on the web

Comment: there are tutorials..but i specifically need for the image captured from camera or gallery

Comment: so you need first use `Canvas.drawImage()` and then you have to call `Canvas.drawParagraph()` - that way you will have an image drawn first and then on top of that image you will have your paragraph text