# How to pass data from StatefulWidget to StatefulWidget, (error)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am totally flutter beginner.

What I want to do is pass the data (by TextController) from StatefulWidget to another one.

Here is my code (passive Widget)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class VocabularyText extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;

  // ignore: sort_constructors_first
  const VocabularyText ({ Key key, this.text }): super(key: key);

  @override
  _VocabularyTextState createState() => _VocabularyTextState();
}

class _VocabularyTextState extends State<VocabularyText> {
  Offset offset = Offset.zero;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Positioned(
        left: offset.dx,
        top: offset.dy,
        child: GestureDetector(
            onPanUpdate: (details) {
              setState(() {
                offset = Offset(
                    offset.dx + details.delta.dx, offset.dy + details.delta.dy);
              });
            },
            child: const SizedBox(
              width: 300,
              height: 300,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                      'a',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 28,
                          color: Colors.red
                      )
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The thing is here

```
                  child: Text(
//
                      widget.text,
//
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 28,
                          color: Colors.red
                      )
                  ),
```

According to my research, this should work, but it doesn't. Why did I make a mistake?

Here is references

- [How to add a draggable "textfield" to add text over images in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57971875/how-to-add-a-draggable-textfield-to-add-text-over-images-in-flutter)
- [Passing Data to a Stateful Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50818770/passing-data-to-a-stateful-widget)

Thank you in advance.

#### edit

[image: a]

[image: b]

Comment: i answered you may want to take a look .

Comment: Thank you, I am going to read it. If I could not get it, I would ask you again. sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i answered before seeing the image it wasn't there
after seeing the image
what causing the problem is this

```
widget.text
```

the correct way to use it in Text widget is like this

```
Text('${widget.text}'),
```

i would suggest that you do the following

to send data to Statefull Widget first you use Navigator or any other method to open this widget to the user like so

```
               return GestureDetector(
                           onTap: () => {
                             Navigator.push(
                               context,
                               MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => 
                               //note here between the () you pass the variable
                              Categories(companies[index].id, companies[index].name)),
                             )},
```

and then to receive them you do like this in my case its Categories Class

```
class Categories extends StatefulWidget {
  //getting company id from home page
  final int companyId;
  final companyName;
  Categories(this.companyId , this.companyName);
  @override
  _CategoriesState createState() => _CategoriesState();
}



class _CategoriesState extends State<Categories> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
...... rest of the code
```

and now to use the data you can do like this for example

```
widget.companyId
```

this was an example from my code now lets jump to your code

to receive the text from the text editing controller you do

```
class TextReceiver extends StatefulWidget {
  //getting company id from home page
  final String userInput;
  TextReceiver(this.userInput);
  @override
  TextReceiver createState() => _TextReceiver();
}
//to use it
widget.userInput
```

now to send it you send it through Material Navigator

```
                       onTap: () => {
                         Navigator.push(
                           context,
                           MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TextReceiver(TextEditingController.text)),
                         )},
```

note that you should pass it as TextEditingController.text because the constructor in TextReceiver is specifying the type to String if you passed TextEditingController then the type wouldn't be String it will be TextEditingController type

all of this code is for example and it would't be like your code but it will give you the idea

refer to official docs https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

Edit : remove `const` from this line

```
child: const SizedBox(
  rest of the code
)

to this

 child: SizedBox(
   rest of the code
 )
```

Comment: Still, I got the same error.... And I may make you understand in a wrong way. I would like to make an upper widget receiver.

Comment: i don't understand it should work please share with us what is written in the error

Comment: did you try this `Text('${widget.text}'),`

Comment: ok after a little research i would suggest you remove `const` word which is located in the sized box line

Comment: AnyTime. Happy to be of assistance